# How about harmonic functinons converges a function?

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes

QUESTION: A harmonic functions converges to a function, how about this function will be?

In fact, we know that, if the convergence is uniformlly, the function is harmonnic.

Furthermore, if the sequence is bounded for below or upper, the function is also harmonic by using the theorem of controled convergence.

If the sequence is not bounded, can we get the harmonic property?